# jquery OR selector in complex selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following selector:

```
$(".product_tile:nth-child(6n) .tile_back select[name='crust']")
```

It finds every 6th product_tile, then gets the child div with the tile_back class, and then inside that the select box with the name crust. I now need to modify this so that it finds one of two select boxes - either crust or base.

I know that in a basic selector, I could use a comma:

```
$("select[name='crust'], select[name='base']")
```

But if I use the comma-delimited selector inside the original selector, will it know that the comma only applies to the last part of it, or will it see it as "find every 6th product_tile's tile_back's crust select box OR find any select box named base"? And if it's the latter, how can I write the selector so that it sees it as "find every 6th product_tile's tile_back's crust select box OR find every 6th product_tile's tile_back's base select box"?

Comment: the comma doesn't do anything special, it just splits the selector into two separate selectors. Try selecting as much as you can without the comma, then use .filter or .find to do the part with the comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to put the logic in the selector. You'll either have to have both full selectors with the comma:

```
$(".product_tile:nth-child(6n) .tile_back select[name='crust'], product_tile:nth-child(6n) .tile_back select[name='base']")
```

or use one selector to match until `.tile_back` and filter with a second selector:

```
$(".product_tile:nth-child(6n) .tile_back").find("select[name='crust'], select[name='base']")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the context for it to search.. using the [context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) like this

```
$("select[name='crust'], select[name='base']",'.product_tile:nth-child(6n) .tile_back')
```

is initially the same as

```
$('.product_tile:nth-child(6n) .tile_back').find("select[name='crust'], select[name='base']");
```

Where it will find all selects with name=crust or name=base under .product_tile:nth-child(6n)

Answer (score 1):

No, just add the beginning part after the comma:

```
$(".product_tile:nth-child(6n) .tile_back select[name='crust'], .product_tile:nth-child(6n) .tile_back select[name='base']")
```

Answer (score 1):

The [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method adds the selected elements to the result set:

```
$(".product_tile:nth-child(6n) .tile_back").add("select[name='crust']").add("select[name='base']");
```